# Libreoffice .docx Macro - PHP

Tags: php, libreoffice

Olá,

É possível rodar uma macro do libreoffice pelo php? algo como:

```
"c:/Program Files/LibreOffice/program/soffice" --nologo --norestore --nolockcheck "macro:///Standard.Module2.PysIndexer(C:\wamp\www\site\public\file.docx)"
```

Macro:

```
sub PysIndexer(docPath as string)

dim document as object
dim dispatcher as object
dim pdfPath as string

dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
dim args2(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue

if fileExists(docPath) then

    args1(0).Name = "Hidden"
    args1(0).Value = True

    args2(0).Name = "FilterName"
    args2(0).Value = "writer_pdf_Export"

    document = starDesktop.loadComponentFromUrl(convertToUrl(docPath), "_blank", 0, args1())

    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document.CurrentController.Frame, ".uno:UpdateAllIndexes", "", 0, array())

    GlobalScope.BasicLibraries.LoadLibrary("Tools")
    pdfPath = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(docPath) & ".pdf"
    document.storeToURL(convertToUrl(pdfPath), args2())

    document.close(True)
end if

end sub
```

O comando funciona se for executado no windows, mas não funciona usando o exec ou shell_exec do php. A minha duvida é se o apontamento macro:/// é reconhecido apenas pelo usuário do windows e se existe alguma outra forma de chamar a macro para que o php possa reconhecer.

Eu encontrei essa macro no seguinte link e acabei atualizando um pouco o código.
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/46586/how-to-automatically-update-indices-in-headless-mode/

PS.: Ainda não sei se essa é a melhor solução, mas foi a única que encontrei por enquanto para atualizar "automaticamente" o sumario de um arquivo com o libreoffice sem a opção de atualizar manualmente (abrir o arquivo atualizar o sumário e fechar).